# htaccess url point to subfolder

Tags: apache, .htaccess

my root subfolders are  like this

Root (www.example.co.uk)

- my_framework
- my_images

I want if the user requested example.com to be point to example.com/my_framework (which is with cakephp) but in url shows www.example.com

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.co.uk$ [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.co.uk$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !example.co.uk/
RewriteRule ^(.*) http://www.example.co.uk/my_framework/$1 [R=301,L]
```

and also when user wants to see the images in some pages images are in my_images folder so they can have access to see this images.

Comment: You should instead edit the apache config file to direct your domain to the my_framework folder. Then cakePHP will have a public assets folder for your images to go in.

Comment: my application images are in app/webroot/img but I have image uploader which uploads my images to mydomain/elfinder/files/images_directories. So I need this mydomain/elfinder/files/images_directories image path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this rule:

```
RewriteEngine on

#this OR and third line accept www from url
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?glamestates.co.uk$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^((?!my_framework/).*)$ /my_framework/$1 [NC,L]
```

Comment: Thank you mate. I vote you up and edited the answer. there is small problem for my_images folder how to fix the requests for that?. here is the link http://www.glamestates.co.uk/elfinder/files/3/images1.jpg as you see it is redirectting to my_framework folder

Comment: ok check updated answer and for images/css/js it is better to use  absolute path in your css, js, images files rather than a relative one. Which means you have to make sure path of these files start either with `http://` or a slash `/`.

Comment: If those file names are valid then you should be able to access them with current rule.